# PHP script flashing on screen during processing

Tags: php

I have an HTML form that runs two seperate php scripts to process. One is a form handler from Tectite (formmail.php), the other is a script that creates an array of uploaded images (upload.php) and sends them to a temp directory on my server.

Everything works as expected except for an odd flash of code that appears right before the user is redirected to the success page. The code appears to be the array created by upload.php.

I can not figure out how to eliminate this flash of code that occurs during processing. You can see it live by filling out the form at pmd-fla.com/test.html. You will need to upload at least one image file so the upload.php script fires.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

This is the upload.php code:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
$img = $_FILES['img'];

if(!empty($img))
{
    $img_desc = reArrayFiles($img);
    print_r($img_desc);

    foreach($img_desc as $val)
    {
        $newname = date('YmdHis',time()).mt_rand().'';
        move_uploaded_file($val['tmp_name'],'./uploads/'.$newname);
    }
}

function reArrayFiles($file)
{
    $file_ary = array();
    $file_count = count($file['name']);
    $file_key = array_keys($file);

    for($i=0;$i<$file_count;$i++)
    {
        foreach($file_key as $val)
        {
            $file_ary[$i][$val] = $file[$val][$i];
        }
    }
    return $file_ary;
}
```

The handlers.php script simply calls the other the two scripts as such:

```
<?php

  include('upload.php');
  include('relay2.php');

?>
```

The relay2.php is really formmail.php from Tectite. It is a huge script, so I won't add it here. This script does contain error checking and validation, but I think the problem is with the upload.php script.

As you can see upload.php contains both echo and print commands, but I do not have the scripting chops to edity the file without breaking it.

Comment: Are you echoing or printing anything anywhere? It could be that you're printing it out before dong anything with it? - It might help to have some code snippets.

Comment: can you paste the "flash of code" here?

Comment: It's either code you are printing out before redirecting as @Will suggests, or you have error reporting enabled and some sort of notice/warning is being triggered. Either way, without examples of the code we cannot do much but speculate. I would suggest readin through upload.php before the redirect to establish what is happening.

Comment: My guess is that you're somehow printing out the post array, which looks like code, but isn't. Without your code we'll never know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look in the file handlers.php to find your answer.

Looking at the flash of code it looks like there is a print_r function that is printing an array used by the program to assess the submitted data. When I tested it there appeared to be a error counter.

As Darragh Enright has said we would need to see the code to be able to tell you for certain where and why the array is being printed.

My suspicion is that the array is being printed because there are errors being found.
What the errors are and why I could not say at this point.

EDIT:

$img is holding uploaded files which is apparently not empty.

```
if(!empty($img))
```

This line is printing the code spinet you are seeing which looks to be summarizing the uploads.

```
print_r($img_desc);
```

You could comment out the line by making it look like this:
`//print_r($img_desc);`

Comment: Thanks to all who have responded. Your time and effort are much appreciated. I have updated the question with code added. I think that, as all have suggested, it has something to do with the print function in upload.php, but I am unclear how to edit the code without breaking it. I tried removing echo '<pre>'; and the script worked, but it did not eliminate the flash.

Comment: $img is holding uploaded files which is apparently not empty.

if(!empty($img))
This line is printing the code spinet you are seeing which looks to be summarizing the uploads.

print_r($img_desc);
You could comment out the line by making it look like this: //print_r($img_desc);

Answer (score 0):

Thanks again for your guidance. I have resolved the issue simply by removing the print function. The new code looks like this:

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';
$img = $_FILES['img'];

if(!empty($img))
{
    $img_desc = reArrayFiles($img);

    foreach($img_desc as $val)
    {
        $newname = date('YmdHis',time()).mt_rand().'';
        move_uploaded_file($val['tmp_name'],'./uploads/'.$newname);
    }
}

function reArrayFiles($file)
{
    $file_ary = array();
    $file_count = count($file['name']);
    $file_key = array_keys($file);

    for($i=0;$i<$file_count;$i++)
    {
        foreach($file_key as $val)
        {
            $file_ary[$i][$val] = $file[$val][$i];
        }
    }
    return $file_ary;
}
```

Thanks again for your guidance. @Steven Woods I upvoted your answer. Cheers.